# Chrome browser automatically scrolling down the content (when nobody asked it to)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have rich page where we have one little block with dynamic content. Everything worked just fine until recently.

Now Chrome browser somehow "capture" the one div on the page and scroll down the whole content. It's hard to explain in words, but much easier to demonstrate.

Here is test page. Just open it in Chrome, and scroll a little bit down so the one of the blue boxes will be on the very top border of viewport. You will see that all content (numbers 1,2,3..) is scrolling by itself when the blue box stays on same place.

It may looks logical in this simple example, but consider that the dynamic block is only one of many blocks on the page and there's no reason to scroll the whole content because something changing inside the block.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="x" style="border:solid 1px red;width:200;height:200">
</div>

1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>


<script>
setInterval(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.setAttribute("style", "border:solid 2px blue;width:100px;height:20px");

    var x = document.getElementById('x');
    x.insertBefore(e, x.childNodes.length?x.childNodes[0]:null);
}, 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

We just discovered this Chrome weird behavoir this week. The code worked fine for last 6 months, so I think it's something new that Chrome made. All other browsers works fine.

**== UPDATE ==**

Using **Chrome** (I have latest v. 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)) to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ and scroll down until "Live searches" (box with moving words) appears on the very top of your browser. You will experience that instead of normal behavior, the whole page starts moving.

Comment: Platform?  Version?  Does not scroll on 56.0.2924.87 for Linux.

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). We also was able to reproduce on different machines, and we have multiple user reports.

Comment: You've scrolled past the element you are inserting into, it's logical browser behaviour to try and keep you at your current viewport while elements are being added above

Comment: JSFiddle with code: https://jsfiddle.net/seajbsjt/  Note that it doesn't behave the same way as the free dictionary link specified.  I don't think you've captured the correct portion of code yet.

Comment: Interesting find. What's your question?

Comment: Note that this is only in Chrome and only in the latest version, because it was not the case before ("Live Searches" here for a while it it was working fine a couple of months ago when I coded it).

Comment: Repeatable behavior on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: The question is how to fix it. The behaviour may be logical for the case if there is only one column. But when we have multiple columns like in thefreedictionary.com homepage, it's not quite logical to move all the page around just because content of one column had been changed.

Comment: @DanEsparza -- it's important to make the moving boxes appears next to the top corner of the browser. The fiddle shows up content in the bottom right cell, so I can't move the blue box anywhere close to the top corner, so why you can't reproduce it in **fiddle**. But you can just save the page in *.htm file and open it in Chrome and will see the same behaviour as in thefreedictionary.com.

Comment: It's the removing of the (now invisible) child elements out of view that seems to be causing the scrolling. Here's a fiddle forked from @DanEsparza's that reproduces the behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/nkjhgg8x/1/

Comment: @Bewusstsein No, it's not removing, but adding elements causing scrolling, at least on thefreedictionary. I just checked it by commenting out node-removing code and the behavior doesn't change.

Answer (score 37):

This could be happening because of the scroll anchoring feature of chrome 56, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/scroll-anchoring, https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5700102471548928

Workaround to fix this issue is to set `overflow-anchor: none;` on parent element. For your reference website

```
#dvLiveSearch{
   overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

This would fix the weird behavior on chrome.

Comment: @MikeKeskinov you have to give the bounty or a check manually. If you don't, he will receive only a half of the bounty. The other half will disappear.

Comment: Where do you add it? I tried adding to body, html, to elements that has content, it doesn't help, chrome still keeps scrolling. Any updates, thought?

Comment: @pakalbekim my answer was specific to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ website, it has an element with the id of `dvLiveSearch`, so the solution was to add CSS for it. It's hard for me to tell where to add this CSS for your situation.

Comment: @azs06 thanks for the response, I experience the same issue on chrome at http://gr.arminaskazlauskas.com/news/1 Not consistently, but if I click around I get scrolled to the bottom very quickly. Maybe you can offer your insights?

Comment: @pakalbekim Your issue doesn't seem to be relevant, though it's only happening on Chrome. Adding `overflow-anchor: none` to the body doesn't solve this issue. The issue seems to be related to your modals at the bottom, adding `.modal{display: none;}`  this does solve the problem, could be because of the tabindex.

Comment: @azs06 this is it! I don't know how you figured it out, but that fixed it! Thank you very much, you saved a ton of time, for me!

Comment: Thank you! fixed my issue. This was a hard one to find for a single line of css