# Content shifts slightly on page reload with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` that has it's left and top offsets chosen randomly from an array of values on page load. It works for the most part, but once in a while, if you refresh, the window gets scrolled down slightly, exposing the next section, and all the content gets cut pushed very slightly to the left. Here are some screenshots of this undesired behavior. This is what the window looks like after a refresh.

[image: Left offset]

[image: Window scrolls down]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="about-section section">

    <div class="about-section__container">
        <h2 class="section-header about-section__header">About me.</h2>

        <p class="about-section__paragraph"></p>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

```
.section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.about-section {
    background-image: url("../../../mountain-background.png.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.about-section__container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.about-section__header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
}
```

```
var title = $('.about-section__container');

var xIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var yIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

var leftMargs = ['20%', '25%', '30%', '35%'];
var topMargs = ['25%', '30%', '35%', '40%'];

title.css({
    'left': leftMargs[xIndex],
    'top': topMargs[yIndex],
    'visibility': 'visible'
    });
```

Another thing to note is that this works perfectly in Edge and Firefox, but only Chrome produces this behavior. It seems like the offset of the text container is somehow affecting the rest of the content, as if you refresh and the text moves to a random position to the left of the previous position, everything gets shifted left, and if it moves down on refresh it causes the browser to scroll down.

Also, this only occurs if you refresh, but never on a first visit.

Is this a problem with my Javascript or is the styling of my section containers or background wrong? Or is it something with the way Chrome caches the CSS? I have no clue as to what else I could possibly try, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cache could be the problem. Try clearing the cache of your Chrome

Comment: can you please create a js fiddle with the issue?

Comment: @hans-könig I tried that many times

Comment: I have added !important to section height and the issue is not existing for me anymore. Can you please check if its working on your side?                                      
`.section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh !important;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: @AkbarAli Works like a charm, thanks. I still wish I understood why it's only chrome that causes this. If you post this comment as an answer I can mark it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add this in your css

```
.section { 
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 100vh !important; 
    z-index: 1; 
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Or You can add `overflow-anchor: none;` It works fine as well. I just found this link with the same issue [Chrome Browser automatically scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308209/chrome-browser-automatically-scrolling-down-the-content-when-nobody-asked-it-to/42562623)